# If f is holomorphic in all $\Bbb{C}$ and $f(z)=f(1-\cos(z))$ $\forall z$, is f necessarily a constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Today I had Theory of Complex Variable Functions exam and I really want to know how to solve this exercise:

> If f is holomorphic in all $\Bbb{C}$ and $f(z)=f(1-\cos(z))$ $\forall
> z$, is f necessarily a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Write $f(z) = f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k z^k$. If $f$ is non-constant, there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $a_n \neq 0$. Then with $g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{n+k}z^k$, we have

$$ f(z) = f(0) + z^n g(z). $$

Plugging this to $f(z) = f(1-\cos z$), we obtain

$$ z^n g(z) = (1-\cos z)^n g(1-\cos z). $$

By noting that $1-\cos z = \mathcal{O}(z^2)$ as $z\to 0$, however,

$$ a_n = g(0) = \lim_{z\to0} \frac{(1-\cos z)^n g(1-\cos z)}{z^n} = 0, $$

which is a contradiction.

---

To grasp the logic of this argument, you may consider the following simpler question first: If $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is entire and satisfies $f(z) = f(z^2)$, does this imply that $f$ is constant?

Comment: An intuitive explanation: $f(0)=0$, for sufficiently small $z$ the behavior of $f(z)$ is like $z^n$ for some $n$, but if $f(z)=f(1-\cos(z))$ then the behavior of $f(z)$ must *also* be like $z^{2n}$ for some $n$, since $f(1-\cos(z))$ is like $f(z^2)$ which is like $z^{2n}$. The only way for $Cz^n$ and $Cz^{2n}$ to have the same local behavior at $z=0$ is if $C=0$.

Comment: @Ian, You are right. I went too meticulous when the essence is to compare the terms of the smallest non-zero degree in both sides.

Comment: I was also sloppy in saying $f(0)=0$, but of course this can be assumed WLOG anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $1 - \cos(0) = 0$.  If $f$ is not constant, there exist some positive integer $n$ and $c \in \mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$ such that $f(z) = f(0) + c z^n + O(z^{n+1})$ as $z \to 0$.  But this is also $$f(1-\cos(z)) = f(0) + c (1-\cos(z))^n + O((1-\cos(z))^n) = f(0) + z^{2n}/2^n + O(z^{2n+2})$$